# Pause (with read or similar) in xargs

Tags: shell-script, xargs, read

I have a script that looks something like the following.

```
find /path -type f |
sed -re 'stuff' |
xargs -Ix sh -c '{
  echo "information about x"
  ./exe < x
  read
}'
```

My goal is to provide each file given to `xargs` as input to `exe`. However, I do not want the output of `exe` to be provided all at once. Instead, I wish to study output of `exe` for each file, and then continue once I am done studying that output. Hence, I have `read`.

The problem is, `read` does not work seem here. Upon executing the script, all output was produced. Are there any suggestions on how one might solve this problem?

Note that I am *not* looking for a way to sleep the execution of `xargs`. Rather, I am looking for a way to pause `xargs`, potentially indefinitely, until the user wishes to continue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redirect the input to `read` from `/dev/tty` like this:

```
read reply < /dev/tty
```

You can accomplish effectively the same results within the shell, without using `xargs` and without directly executing a new shell to process each file:

```
find /path -type f |
sed -re 'stuff' |
while IFS= read -r x
do
    echo "information about $x"
    ./exe < "$x"
    read reply < /dev/tty
done
```

I think you'll find that this method is more efficient (not really an issue in this interactive situation), more portable, requires less syntax, and is easier to read and maintain.